# English confuses me sometimes

Tags: present-perfect-vs-simple-past

I posted something online and someone said it was wrong so... 
I said : I just changed my phone number.
That person said that i should have said : I have just changed my phone number. 
Which one was the correct version?

Comment: They are both grammatical.